# AWS S3: Limit the number of objects a user can access in a 10-minute window

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a UseCase which limits the number of objects that a user can access to
10 in a 10 minute window.

The users request for download/upload from their mobile devices through a mobile app.

Is there a way to implement this in AWS S3?

Comment: Can you please Edit your question to add additional information about what you are actually trying to _achieve_? The more information you provide, the more likely we can provide a suitable answer. Please add information such as how users are identified (do they login first?), _why_ you wish to limit access (is it due to costs?), and what problems you are currently facing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. Amazon S3 does not have the ability to limit the number of objects a user can access. If they can access an object, they can do it as many times as they wish.

A couple of options for you:

**API Gateway**

Rather than allowing users to go directly to Amazon S3, they could request objects via an API Gateway, which calls an AWS Lambda function. This function could then verify whether they are permitted to access the object and, if so, provides the content of the object.

**Pre-Signed URLs**

Rather than making an object publicly-accessible, it could be kept as **private**. Then, when a user wishes to access the object in Amazon S3, your application can generate a **pre-signed URL**, which provides time-limited access to the object (eg 5 minutes). Once this time period expires, the URL will no longer work.

See: [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I guess you are referring to the lambda function as app. 
Can the lambda function fulfill  both these conditions:

No user can request for more than 10 objects in a 10 minute window and
once we hit the 50 requests (from all users) in a 10 minute window, it should not allow the 51st request.

Comment: You would need to write the AWS Lambda function yourself. It would also need some concept as to how a "user" is defined. I would recommend using pre-signed URLs, but would need more information about your system to be sure.

Comment: I am planning to use a mobile app called s3 manager to request upload/download pictures from their mobile device. Can this mobile app call the Lambda function directly?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question (or create a new question) with full details of your situation, as per my comment added to your question.